# How would I create an array after modifying its contents, then insert it into a single database cell?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm currently working with the `$_FILES` array, however I am wondering how it would be possible to insert values into a single cell within the database as an array after each of the specified objects within that array have been modified.

My code below has taken all of the `['tmp_name']`s and added a randomized six digit value before the name of the file. The purpose for this is to prevent any images from being overwritten if the same file path is inserted by other users.

As I cannot place the array as it is into the database, what I would like is for each of the modified `['tmp_name']`s to be placed back into an array, then inserted into the database with their new values. I'd then like to know how to grab the array from the database cell and put it back into a while loop to display on another page.

Thanks in advance, Rich

**Here is my code so far, if anyone could shed some light on how I could achieve this it'd be much appreciated:**

```
$i = 0;
$countFiles = count($_FILES['upload1']['tmp_name']);
while ($i < $countFiles) {
$imgName1 = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.]#i", "", $_FILES['upload1']['name'][$i]);
$imgName1 = mt_rand(100000, 999999).$imgName1;
move_uploaded_file($imgTmp1[$i], "images/$imgName1");
    $i++;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO articles (title, articleContent, date, image) SELECT '".$title."', '".$articleContent."', now(), '".$imgName1."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize() to store arrays in database

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3);
$str = serialize($arr); // Store the string in db
```

To get back the array use unserialize()

```
$arr = unserialize($str);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Since I'm running the array and modifying the ['tmp_name']s through the while loop, how would I place each item into the array afterwards? I've read into serialize and am unsure how I could use it in this case, haha.

Comment: I think I may have successfully serialized all of the array objects by creating a blank array before the while loop and inserting the items in as `$array[] = $imgName1[$i]; within it`, then serializing that and inserting it into the db. I'm still unsure how to unserialize it and place the file paths into a while loop to echo on another page.

Comment: Get the data from the database and pass it through the unserialize function, that's gonna get you back the array then you could use foreach loop (instead of while loop) to echo it on any page.